# Remove duplicate object in Java 8 and get the sum of String values in the object (first value need to convert in BigDecimal)

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have **class** DTO which have 3 fields.

And I have a list of DTO objects.

I want to do remove all the duplicate object based on **ID** field in the list and get the sum of the value which is string type. First values **convert to Bigdecimal** and then add(Sum) the duplicate object values.

**Note::** Value is string format in the class DTO

```
@AllArgsConstructor
static class DTO {
    int id;
    int year;
    String value;
}

List<DTO> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new DTO(1, 2020, "5.5"));
list.add(new DTO(1, 2020, "-8.0"));
list.add(new DTO(2, 2020, "1.5"));
list.add(new DTO(3, 2020, "4.5"));
list.add(new DTO(3, 2020, "1.5"));
list.add(new DTO(3, 2020, "-9.5"));
list.add(new DTO(4, 2020, "-3.5"));
list.add(new DTO(4, 2020, "7.5"));
list.add(new DTO(4, 2020, "5.5"));
list.add(new DTO(4, 2020, "-7.5"));
```

I've tried a variations of streams, collectors, groupby etc., and I'm lost.

This is what I have so far:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getId()), Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, DTO::getValue, BigDecimal.add()));
```

**Expected**

```
DTO(1, 2021, "-2.5"); (value Sum of group 1)
DTO(2, 2021, "-1.5"); (value Sum of group 2)
DTO(3, 2021, "-3.5"); (value Sum of group 3)
DTO(4, 2021, "2"); (value Sum of group 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method that adds two `DTO`:

```
private static DTO add(DTO dto1, DTO dto2) {
    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(dto1.getValue());
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(dto2.getValue());
    return new DTO(dto1.getId(), dto1.getYear(), bd1.add(bd2).toString());
}
```

Then you can `stream` grouping by `id` and reduce using the previous method:

```
private static List<DTO> add(List<DTO> list) {
    Map<Integer, Optional<DTO>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DTO::getId, 
                Collectors.reducing((d1, d2) -> add(d1, d2))));

    return map.values().stream()
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get).toList();
}
```

Test:

```
List<DTO> list = List.of(
        new DTO(1, 2020, "5.5"),
        new DTO(1, 2020, "-8.0"),
        new DTO(2, 2020, "1.5"),
        new DTO(3, 2020, "4.5"),
        new DTO(3, 2020, "1.5"),
        new DTO(3, 2020, "-9.5"),
        new DTO(4, 2020, "-3.5"),
        new DTO(4, 2020, "7.5"),
        new DTO(4, 2020, "5.5"),
        new DTO(4, 2020, "-7.5"));

List<DTO> listAdded = add(list);
    
listAdded.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
DTO[1, 2020, -2.5]
DTO[2, 2020, 1.5]
DTO[3, 2020, -3.5]
DTO[4, 2020, 2.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this I would not use streams but the merge method which takes the current value and applies it to the existing one, which in this case is the instance that holds the sums.

```
List<DTO> list = List.of(new DTO(1, 2020, "5.5"),
        new DTO(1, 2020, "-8.0"), new DTO(2, 2020, "1.5"),
        new DTO(3, 2020, "4.5"), new DTO(3, 2020, "1.5"),
        new DTO(3, 2020, "-9.5"), new DTO(4, 2020, "-3.5"),
        new DTO(4, 2020, "7.5"), new DTO(4, 2020, "5.5"),
        new DTO(4, 2020, "-7.5"));

Map<String, DTO> map = new HashMap<>();

for (DTO dto : list) {
    map.merge(dto.getId() + "_" + dto.getYear(), dto, (sum, dt) -> new DTO(
            sum.getId(), sum.getYear(),
            new BigDecimal(sum.getValue())
                    .add(new BigDecimal((dt.getValue())))
                    .toString()));
}

map.values().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
DTO[1, 2020, -2.5]
DTO[2, 2020, 1.5]
DTO[3, 2020, -3.5]
DTO[4, 2020, 2.0]
```

If you want to place the results in a list you can do.

```
List<DTO> newList = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Besides getters and setters, I am using the following toString for output.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
        return "%s[%d, %d, %s]".formatted(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),id, year, value);
}
```

But if you really want to use a stream, then you can do like so.

- Stream the objects
- Collect using toMap
- and use toMap's merge method to sum the values.

```
Map<String, DTO> result = list.stream().collect(Collectors
        .toMap(dto->dto.getId()+"_"+dto.getYear(), dto -> dto, (sum, dto) -> new DTO(
                sum.getId(), sum.getYear(),
                new BigDecimal(sum.getValue())
                        .add(new BigDecimal((dto.getValue())))
                        .toString())));
```

Comment: Thanks @WJS really amazing to learn merge function with this example.

Comment: what I need to do the change if year also got change in each rows in the result like year 2020 to 2021

Comment: @RishiKumar  Very simple.  Just change the Map to `Map<String,DTO>`and then change `DTO:getId` to `dto.getId()+"_"+dto.getYear()` as shown in my updated example.  That will associate the year and the ID together.  This will work for both my merge and stream examples.

Comment: In the stream version with toMap you need to prefix it the key argument with `dto->` like `toMap(dto->dto.getId()+"_"+dto.getYear(),...`